# studio.sh (Android Studio) not opening on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, android-studio

Had installed Android Studio on Ubuntu. Later switched from unity to KDE but now the studio.sh file is not opening.

Error: Could not find the program '/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'
[plasma error]